# Powershell run SQL job, delay, then run the next one

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am writing a Powershell script that does several things with a local SQL Server database.

One thing I am doing is running several SQL jobs, one after another.  I run them like this:

```
 sqlcmd -S .\ -Q "EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Rebuild Content Asset Relationship Data'"
```

Is there a way to get Powershell to delay running the next job until the first one is completed?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean delay a number of seconds?  Or does `sqlcmd` not wait until the sproc is done before it exits?

Comment: Mike:  it does not wait.  As soon as you execute the command it returns 0.001 seconds later with this:  

`Job 'Rebuild Content Asset Relationship Data' started successfully.`

Comment: So your query technically completes, it just starts some background process in SQL Server.  The question is how in the world would Powershell know when some SQL Server process was finished?  Maybe you can poll every x seconds to check if it's done yet?

Comment: That's correct.  It starts and eventually completes.  How and what do I poll every few seconds?  Is that the best way to do it?  is there just a flag I can add to SQLcmd?

Comment: A quick Google turned up this: http://www.interworks.com/blogs/bbickell/2010/01/15/how-execute-and-monitor-agent-job-using-t-sql-sql-server-20052008 - Maybe wrap the whole thing in a sproc that starts the job, then loops until the job is complete.  Then call that from Powershell..

Comment: Sleeping and polling can be tricky and unreliable ways to manage dependencies for SQL jobs. It might be more effective to create a new wrapper job at the database level, with a step for each child job. Then you can call that single job from Powershell if you like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get access to SQL Agent Jobs from PowerShell you can use SMO:

**EDIT**: *Thinking on efficiency if you are going to add this function to your script I would take the SMO loading out and just place it near the top of your script (prior to this function). It will probably slow your script down if every time you call the function it reloads the assembly.*

```
Function Get-SQLJobStatus
{
    param ([string]$server, [string]$JobName)
    # Load SMO assembly, and if we're running SQL 2008 DLLs load the SMOExtended and SQLWMIManagement libraries
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null

    # Create object to connect to SQL Instance
    $srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $server

    # used to allow piping of more than one job name to function
    if($JobName)
    {
        foreach($j in $jobName)
        {
            $srv.JobServer.Jobs | where {$_.Name -match $JobName} | Select Name, CurrentRunStatus
        }
    }
    else #display all jobs for the instance
    {
        $srv.JobServer.Jobs | Select Name, CurrentRunStatus
} #end of Get-SQLJobStatus
}
```

Example of ways you could use this function:

```
#will display all jobs on the instance
Get-SQLJobStatus MyServer

#pipe in more than one job to get status
"myJob","myJob2" | foreach {Get-SQLJobStatus -Server MyServer -JobName $_}

#get status of one job
Get-SQLJobStatus -Server MyServer -JobName "MyJob"
```

You could utilize this function in your script and just repeatedly call it in a while loop or something until your job status shows "Idle". At least in my head that is what I think could work :)

Comment: It seems to work but I am always getting "idle" for all jobs.  If I run the job from powershell using the line in my original post... or even if I run the job from "Microsoft SQL server management Studio"... I still get "Idle" for all jobs.  Not sure what to do.

I make sure to set the server to "./".

I know it kind of works because if I request status of a job that doesn't exist it gives me nothing.

any thoughts?

Comment: So you are calling the job to start and then check the status with the function? If you look at the job history what how long did the job take to run? The only thing that might help is to possibly check for last run date to be greater than current time. I'm not sure if that would work in your situation.

Comment: Ignore my comment above for now... I think I have more work to do on my part... your code may be solid.

Comment: Thanks... I'm an idiot... your code worked perfectly.  The problem was I was testing it on my local box with a small SQL job that finished executing very quickly.  When I tried it on the production server with the SQL job that took 5 minutes to finish then I started to see "Idle" change to "Executing".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, execute a `Start-Sleep -seconds <nn>` between invocations of sqlcmd.exe.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specefied that I would prefer not to use sleep.  Some of these jobs take 5 minutes to run.  This time can vary wildly depending on the speed of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to wrap your job in a new sproc that starts the job then waits for it to finish by continually polling its status.  From the [attached article](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/bbickell/2010/01/15/how-execute-and-monitor-agent-job-using-t-sql-sql-server-20052008), you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @JobStatus INT
SET @JobStatus = 0
EXEC MSDB.dbo.sp_start_job @Job_Name = 'JobName'
SELECT @JobStatus = current_execution_status  FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
                          'EXEC MSDB.dbo.sp_help_job @job_name = ''JobName'', @job_aspect = ''JOB'' ')     
WHILE @JobStatus <> 4
BEGIN   
    SELECT @JobStatus = current_execution_status  FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
                                'EXEC MSDB.dbo.sp_help_job @job_name = ''JobName'', @job_aspect = ''JOB'' ')    
END
```

Then, rather than calling `sp_start_job` from the command line, call your sproc from the command line and PowerShell will be blocked until that sproc finishes.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your job is executed by SQL Server Agent. Either you call the corresponding stored proc (or SQL Statements) directly from your PowerShell script, or you implement something in the line of what is explained [here.](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/bbickell/2010/01/15/how-execute-and-monitor-agent-job-using-t-sql-sql-server-20052008)