# How to run a Microsoft SQL Server Agent Job from VBScript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I have an ERP system that allows me to attach VBScript to a button on a customized window. I would like to be able to run this script so that it fires off a SQL Server Agent Job on the server (SQL Server 2008). I've been looking in to this for a couple hours now and the closest thing I could see was a short script which seems to use a depreciated command (SQL.DMO). Here's the code I swiped from the web:

```
On Error Goto 0: Main() 
Sub Main() 
  Set objSQL = CreateObject("SQLDMO.SQLServer")
  ' Leave as trusted connection
  objSQL.LoginSecure = True
  ' Change to match the name of your SQL server
  objSQL.Connect "Server Name"
  Set objJob = objSQL.JobServer
  For each job in objJob.Jobs
   if instr(1,job.Name,"Job Name") > 0 then
     msgbox job.Name
     job.Start
     msgbox "Job Started"
   end if
  Next
End Sub
```

The resulting error is:

```
Line:  3
Char:  3
Error:  ActiveX component can't create object:  'SQLDMO.SQLServer'
Code:  800A01AD
Source:  Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

Comment: I'd guess that you need some (deprecated) SQL Server related stuff installed on your client to get this to work. If everything else fails, you could always have your VBScript fire off a [PowerShell script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10197883/205233).

Comment: How this would work depends totally on the client where the vbscript is executing.  Will these clients have SQL Server libraries installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) and execute [sp_start_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) command:

```vb
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "sqlcmd -S localhost -E -Q ""EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'My Job Name'""
```

`sqlcmd` should exist on the SQL Server.

### Note:

This is a potential a security risk. As per documentation, by default, only members of **sysadmin** role can execute `sp_start_job`. You will need your VBScript to run under security context of a user that has **sysadmin** privileges in the SQL Server (which is not good).

**Use Task Scheduler and a trigger file**

Rather than starting the SQL Agent Job directly, create a Scheduled Task on the SQL Server that would:

- be scheduled to run every 10 minutes
- execute a cmd script, which would:

  - check for existence of a *trigger file* in a specified location
  - if file is found, would start the SQL Agent Job using `sqlcmd`, and delete the trigger file thereafter

The VBScript triggered by the ERP system should simply place an empty correctly named *trigger file* in the specified location.

**Use a stored procedure to control what is being started**

To further reduce attack vectors, you can create your own wrapper stored procedure in SQL Server that would start the required SQL Agent Job.

1. Create a server Login:

```sql
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [erp_trigger_user] WITH PASSWORD=N'pwd', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[msdb], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
```

2. Create a database user:

```sql
USE [msdb]
GO
CREATE USER [erp_trigger_user] FOR LOGIN [erp_trigger_user] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

3. Create a stored procedure that will start your required SQL Server Agent Job:

**Note:** the stored procedure will execute as **dbo** user, which has permission to execute `msdb.dbo.sp_start_job`.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_StartERPJob
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
AS
BEGIN

    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'My Job Name'

END
```

3. Grant the user permissions to execute the stored procedure:

```sql
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[sp_StartERPJob] TO [erp_trigger_user]
GO
```

4. Update your Scheduled Task to execute a Windows batch file that looks something like this:

```
if exist trigger_file.txt (
    sqlcmd -S localhost -E -Q -U erp_trigger_user -P pwd "EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_StartERPJob"
    del trigger_file.txt
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
)
```